# How to create stored function from Spring using JdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, plsql, jdbctemplate

For administration needs, I need to create and replace stored procedures from Spring Repository. Has anyone already done this?

I tried to use following code(unfinished):

```
@Component
public class JdbcRepository {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbc;

    public void checkConn(){

        jdbc.execute("create or replace package Z$CLIENT_INTERFACE_API as \n" +
                "    function CL_ORG_SEARCH_CREATE(p_request in clob) return clob;\n" +
                "end Z$CLIENT_INTERFACE_API;\n" +
                "/\n" +
                "create or replace package body Z$CLIENT_INTERFACE_API as\n" +
                "    function CL_ORG_SEARCH_CREATE(p_request in clob) return clob\n" +
                "    is\n" +
                "        content_xml VARCHAR2(4000);\n" +
                "        p Dbms_Xmlparser.Parser;\n" +
                "        v_Doc Dbms_Xmldom.Domdocument;\n" +
                "        v_Root_Element Dbms_Xmldom.Domelement;\n" +
                "        v_Child_Nodes Dbms_Xmldom.Domnodelist;\n" +
                "        v_Child_Node Dbms_Xmldom.Domnode;\n" +
                "        v_Message_Id VARCHAR2(36);\n" +
                "        v_First_Char VARCHAR2(1);\n" +
                "    begin\n" +
                "        content_xml:=  CAST(p_request as VARCHAR2);\n" +
                "        p := Dbms_Xmlparser.Newparser;\n" +
                "        dbms_xmlparser.setvalidationmode(p,False);\n" +
                "        dbms_xmlparser.parsebuffer(p,content_xml);\n" +
                "        v_Doc := dbms_xmlparser.getdocument(p);\n" +
                "        v_Root_Element := Dbms_Xmldom.getdocumentelement(v_Doc);\n" +
                "        return 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1';\n" +
                "    end;\n" +
                "end Z$CLIENT_INTERFACE_API;\n" +
                "/");
    }

}
```

But whan I execute it, i take broken package in db. In same time, whan I run this from SQLDeveloper - all works perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are separating statements by both semicolon `;` and slash `/`.
Try using only one of those, but not both. If that doesn't work either, try executing each statement separately with `execute( )`

Answer (score 0):

This works perfect:

```
        jdbc.execute("create or replace package Z$CLIENT_INTERFACE_API as \n" +
                "    function CL_ORG_SEARCH_CREATE(p_request in clob) return clob;\n" +
                "end Z$CLIENT_INTERFACE_API;\n");
        jdbc.execute("create or replace package body Z$CLIENT_INTERFACE_API as\n" +
                        "    function CL_ORG_SEARCH_CREATE(p_request in clob) return clob\n" +
                        "    is\n" +
                        "        content_xml VARCHAR2(4000);\n" +
                        "        p Dbms_Xmlparser.Parser;\n" +
                        "        v_Doc Dbms_Xmldom.Domdocument;\n" +
                        "        v_Root_Element Dbms_Xmldom.Domelement;\n" +
                        "        v_Child_Nodes Dbms_Xmldom.Domnodelist;\n" +
                        "        v_Child_Node Dbms_Xmldom.Domnode;\n" +
                        "        v_Message_Id VARCHAR2(36);\n" +
                        "        v_First_Char VARCHAR2(1);\n" +
                        "    begin\n" +
                        "        content_xml:=  CAST(p_request as VARCHAR2);\n" +
                        "        p := Dbms_Xmlparser.Newparser;\n" +
                        "        dbms_xmlparser.setvalidationmode(p,False);\n" +
                        "        dbms_xmlparser.parsebuffer(p,content_xml);\n" +
                        "        v_Doc := dbms_xmlparser.getdocument(p);\n" +
                        "        v_Root_Element := Dbms_Xmldom.getdocumentelement(v_Doc);\n" +
                        "        return 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1';\n" +
                        "    end;\n" +
                        "end Z$CLIENT_INTERFACE_API;");
```